# Load HTML table on page load appending with URL response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have already tried to get URL responses into a HTML table on click event. But what I actually need is, as soon as I load the page I have to get the URL response displayed in a table.
My script is as follows:

```
window.onload  = function (
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/imp/' ,
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        if(data[i].name && data[i].age){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].name+"</td><td>"+data[i].age+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#impExtTableID").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    );
    return false;//suppress natural form submission });
```

Comment: what are you looking for your script @TEchLearn

Comment: How can I load my index page with the table having all the URL response?

Comment: can you give a `console.log(txt)` above the line `$("#impExtTableID").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");` and see whether you are getting any results there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple i have made a table with your ID, and within tbody i added the content what you got from your request URL,

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload  = function (
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/imp/' ,
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        if(data[i].name && data[i].age){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].name+"</td><td>"+data[i].age+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#impExtTableID tbody").html(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    );
    return false;//suppress natural form submission });
</script>

<body>
   <table id="impExtTableID" class="hidden">
         <thead><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></thead>
         <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
</body>
```

Comment: also can you provide the OUTPUT, i need to check format of that

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you

Comment: Can you also tell me what if I want to make this same table to be loaded when I select one tab from the navBar not to be loaded as soon as the page loads?

Comment: @TEchLearn, in that case you need to make with click event of tab and within click event you need to load data to that table. let me know if you understood, thanks

Comment: Realy sorry! I could not get what you said

Comment: I am suddenly getting an error saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" on line 2 which is - $.ajax({
Can you give me a solution for this error?